# What's the maximum audio time for chunked data in Wit.ai?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, chunked-encoding, wit.ai, chunked

I'm try to send a speech on wit.ai but I did not understand if I'm possible send audio file greater than 10 seconds if I send chunked data less than 10 seconds each one.

Answer (score 0):

Audio stream shouldn’t exceed 10s of audio time.
See below.
 https://wit.ai/docs/http/20170307